# Usage of branches for small changes between different versions in Git

Tags: git, github

I have a project that needs to be served to 2 different clients, in separate URL's, so I have 2 heroku apps to which I push from the same git repository. Let's say my clients are A and B, and I have to make the title of the mainpage "A" in A.herokuapp.com, and "B" in B.herokuapp.com, or I have to use different images/assets for both.

I created two branches in my git repository, named forA and forB. I make specific changes in their own branch, that is OK. However, when I want to make changes to both, I have to make changes in master, then go and rebase each branch. Things get pretty bad here, that page title from master branch replaces in forA and forB.

Is there a way to manage this kind of development with git branches?

Comment: What is your rebase command? There shouldn't be this case unless if you have a forced rebase or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't rebase!

The typical dev cycle would be keeping all the common changes in master, and merging master into forA and forB as needed; that way, you can always keep your customer branches up to date whilst keeping them separate, and also keeping your "core" development independent and free of customer-specific stuff.

Comment: That is a nice solution. However I suppose 2 problem emerges from this solution. First, if I have lets say 100 customers, it takes too much time to merge all of them. Second, we would end up with many conflicts needs to be resolved. Still seems the most logical one. Thanks!